# Android - How to draw small centered circle divider for horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a ItemDecoration for my recyclerView. The item that I am drawing is just a small circle. the circle (looks like a bullet point) will be used to divide the items in a horizontal recyclerView.

the item decorator looks like this:

```
class  MyItemDecoration constructor(context: Context, resId: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

        private var divider: Drawable? = null

        init {
            //custom divider
            divider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId)
        }

        override fun onDraw(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
            drawStuff(c, parent)
        }

        private fun drawStuff(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView) {
            divider?.let {
                val top = it.intrinsicHeight
                val bottom = it.intrinsicWidth

                val childCount = parent.childCount
                for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                    val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
                    val params = child
                            .layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
                    val left = child.right + params.rightMargin
                    val right = left + it.intrinsicHeight
                    it.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)

                    it.draw(c)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the shape that I am drawing looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/red"/>
    <size
        android:width="4dp"
        android:height="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

a simple red circle.

the issue I am having is that I need the circle to be drawn in the vertical center. now it's slightly off. is there a way I can either translate the canvas tto the center or draw the drawable right at the center?

I've tried adjusting the bounds but I can't figure it out still.

Comment: i dont see any reason for any xml drawables here, just use [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) API for drawing whatever you want

Comment: hmm interesting. how to center it ? let me also look. lets say i draw the circle like this:                      c.drawCircle(convertDpToPixel(4).toFloat(), convertDpToPixel(4).toFloat(), convertDpToPixel(8).toFloat(),p)
   how to center it though ? let me try dividing x and y by 2.

Comment: How would i get the x and y from the item decotorator ? how do i know where to draw the circle using the canvas. not sure how to get cx and cy

Comment: you have `RecyclerView parent` - so you can get width of your recycler view here

Comment: I don't think that helps. All I want is a small circle 4dpx4dp to be the divider of my horizontal  list items. The circle should be centered

Comment: what does `parent.getWidth()` return?

Comment: The width of the entire recyclerview.

Comment: and cannot you use it to get the horizontal center? btw there is one implementation of `RecyclerView..ItemDecoration` - `DividerItemDecoration` just use it and you will not have to implement `MyItemDecoration`

Comment: yah i tried using that implementation but it wont keep my shape in the center and at 4dp. can you help . can you show me how you would do it

Comment: just use nine patch drawable or `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class - much more easier than implementing custom `ItemDrcoration`

Comment: as you said i changed my implementation to just use a drawable i hide and show . its a shame i could not get the item decoration to work. i'll leave the question incase anyone can help. thanks for your insight.

Comment: ok so what kind of `Drawable` did you use with `DividerItemDecoration`?

Comment: i dropped the dividerItemDecoration. i just made dividers myself . at the end of every cell i put a image view. o each cell contains a imageView as the as the last element.

Comment: no, dont do that: use this `.9.png` image: https://pasteboard.co/HZ74nhR.png for example